# How to tell Three.js not to use interpolation when zooming an object's texture?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

It is a plane with a sprite art as texture so I'd like it zoomed using no interpolation method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get no interpolation like this:

```
texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
```

However, if you're after a [minecraft look](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_minecraft.html) where there is interpolation in the far areas (less noisy), you'll need this combo:

```
texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
```

Comment: Do you ever sleep? 
Thanks!